# psutil in Apache Spark

Tags: python, pyspark, psutil

I'm using PySpark 1.5.2.   I got `UserWarning Please install psutil to have better support with spilling` after I issue the command `.collect()`

Why is this warning showed?

How can I install `psutil`?

Comment: As far as I know psutil is python module. You could pip install it. `pip install psutil`.

Comment: I issued the `pip` command but doesn't work.  I'm using python 3.5 but spark is using python 2.7.

Answer (score 17):

```
pip install psutil
```

If you need to install specifically for python 2 or 3, try using `pip2` or `pip3`; it works for both major versions. [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) is the PyPI package for psutil.

Answer (score 1):

y can clone or download the psutil project in the following link:
https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil.git

then  run setup.py to install psutil

in 'spark/python/pyspark/shuffle.py' y can see the following codes:

```
def get_used_memory():
    """ Return the used memory in MB """
    if platform.system() == 'Linux':
        for line in open('/proc/self/status'):
            if line.startswith('VmRSS:'):
                return int(line.split()[1]) >> 10

    else:
        warnings.warn("Please install psutil to have better "
                      "support with spilling")**
        if platform.system() == "Darwin":
            import resource
            rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
            return rss >> 20
        # TODO: support windows

    return 0
```

so i guess if yr os is not a linux, so psutil is suggested.