# What does pyspark need psutil for? (faced "UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling")?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm beginning to learn Spark using pyspark and wonder what the meaning of the following log message is?

> UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling

The operation that is causing the spill is a `join` between two RDDs:

```
print(user_types.join(user_genres).collect())
```

This may sound somewhat obvious, but my first question is

I did indeed install `psutil`, and the warning went away, but I'd like to understand what exactly is occurring. There is a [very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503549/psutil-in-apache-spark), but the OP was asking mostly how to just install `psutil`.

Comment: This warning doesn't indicate a spill (it [is invoked on module import](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0ebb0c0d4dd3e192464dc5e0e6f01efa55b945ed/python/pyspark/shuffle.py#L34-L69) before any real processing takes place) - it just means that you don't use GNU/Linux and don't have recommended dependencies installed. Spills, if present, will be visible in a log and / or Spark web UI.

Comment: @Yu Chen Please ask the other questions separately.

Comment: @Yu Chen please accept the answer if you found it useful enough, so that others can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Spill** here means writing the in-memory dataframes to disk, which reduces the performance of pyspark, since writing to disk is slow.

#### Why psutil

To check the used memory of node.

This is the original snippet from pyspark source code shuffle.py taken from [here](https://apache.googlesource.com/spark/+/branch-1.3/python/pyspark/shuffle.py?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F) which throws the warning. Below code defines a function to get the used memory if psutil is present or if the system is linux.

#### importing psutil and defining get_used_memory

```
try:
    import psutil
    def get_used_memory():
        """ Return the used memory in MB """
        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        if hasattr(process, "memory_info"):
            info = process.memory_info()
        else:
            info = process.get_memory_info()
        return info.rss >> 20
except ImportError:
    def get_used_memory():
        """ Return the used memory in MB """
        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            for line in open('/proc/self/status'):
                if line.startswith('VmRSS:'):
                    return int(line.split()[1]) >> 10
        else:
            warnings.warn("Please install psutil to have better "
                          "support with spilling")
            if platform.system() == "Darwin":
                import resource
                rss = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
                return rss >> 20
            # TODO: support windows
        return 0
```

#### Writing to disk

Below code invokes writing the dataframes to disk if used memory of node is greater than pre-set limit.

```
def mergeCombiners(self, iterator, check=True):
        """ Merge (K,V) pair by mergeCombiner """
        iterator = iter(iterator)
        # speedup attribute lookup
        d, comb, batch = self.data, self.agg.mergeCombiners, self.batch
        c = 0
        for k, v in iterator:
            d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else v
            if not check:
                continue
            c += 1
            if c % batch == 0 and get_used_memory() > self.memory_limit:
                self._spill()
                self._partitioned_mergeCombiners(iterator, self._next_limit())
                break
```

#### Spill

This code actually writes aka **spills** the dataframes to disk in case the memory used is greater than preset limit.

```
def _spill(self):
        """
        dump already partitioned data into disks.
        It will dump the data in batch for better performance.
        """
        global MemoryBytesSpilled, DiskBytesSpilled
        path = self._get_spill_dir(self.spills)
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        used_memory = get_used_memory()
        if not self.pdata:
            # The data has not been partitioned, it will iterator the
            # dataset once, write them into different files, has no
            # additional memory. It only called when the memory goes
            # above limit at the first time.
            # open all the files for writing
            streams = [open(os.path.join(path, str(i)), 'w')
                       for i in range(self.partitions)]
            for k, v in self.data.iteritems():
                h = self._partition(k)
                # put one item in batch, make it compatitable with load_stream
                # it will increase the memory if dump them in batch
                self.serializer.dump_stream([(k, v)], streams[h])
            for s in streams:
                DiskBytesSpilled += s.tell()
                s.close()
            self.data.clear()
            self.pdata = [{} for i in range(self.partitions)]
        else:
            for i in range(self.partitions):
                p = os.path.join(path, str(i))
                with open(p, "w") as f:
                    # dump items in batch
                    self.serializer.dump_stream(self.pdata[i].iteritems(), f)
                self.pdata[i].clear()
                DiskBytesSpilled += os.path.getsize(p)
        self.spills += 1
        gc.collect()  # release the memory as much as possible
        MemoryBytesSpilled += (used_memory - get_used_memory()) << 20
```